# Postgres - Spring Data JPA - Autro generate database and tables

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to enable the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` to auto-generate my postgres database, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46035190/edit), but I always get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at br.com.igo.api.IgoApiApplication.main(IgoApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "igoapi" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2586) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:113) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/igoapi?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.session.store-type=none
```

and finally my dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have tested with mysql and all works fine, I have no much experience in postgres with spring, any help is appreciated.
Ps: I'm using Postgres 9.5.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is not created. Either manually create it or change this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
```

for this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but it does not work too, the same error is showed.

Comment: my bad, I think postgresql doesn't support "createDatabaseIfNotExist" although it should create the database if it doesn't exist without any special flag. I see that you're using postgres 9.5.11, but using the PostgreSQL94Dialect. Did you try removing `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect` and `spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL`? These properties are supposed to be detected automatically by spring boot anyway

Comment: Nothing seems to work, I don't know what is wrong, if I create the database manually, the tables are generated, any ideia?

Comment: If you can't create the database with JPA then you'll have to do it manually. Since the tables are generated (as they should), you only have to make sure that the database you want to connect to exists. If you want to automate it you can use an sql script that runs when the application starts (this is relatively straightforward with spring boot)

Comment: I wouldn't mark this as the answer, because it didn't really solve the problem.